# How to keep command prompt open even after getting an output in sublime text 2

Tags: c, windows, command-line, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm learning C through K & R and for it I'm using **Turbo c++ v 4.5**. Since it is and ancient compiler I have been searching for better one and came across Sublime Text 2 editor. **I have managed to create a build file and it works fine to capture errors and to give correct output.**
However, after giving an output, command prompt closes itself within a second.I can barely analyze an output.
I'm using **32-bit windows xp sp3 and MinGW as a compiler**.
Here is my build file :

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc", "-Wall", "-time", "$file" , "-o",  "$file_base_name"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell" : true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Steps I follow:
1.I write program in sublime and build it using above build file.
2.Then I go to folder where I have saved my written programs.
3.I find application file(.exe) of program I've written previously and double click it to open.
4.I enter inputs and command prompt closes itself after a millisecond of printing an output.

So my question : **Is there any way to keep open command prompt for some time or it should be closed when I do it manually. If it is possible please post execution build file for 'C' so I can get output in Sublime itself.**

Comment: Add `getchar()` or `getch()` just before `return 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your build system like so:

```js
{
    "cmd" : ["start", "cmd", "/k", "gcc", "-Wall", "-time", "$file", "-o",  "$file_base_name"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

`"start", "cmd"` opens a new `cmd` window, and the `"/k"` options ensures that it stays open after the subsequent command (in this case, `gcc`) returns. You can now scroll through the compiler's output, and run additional commands if you wish, such as executing the just-built program.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked..:D Can you send me link where command likes '/k' are available and explained also.

Comment: the "shell" key was essential to me. Thanks!